# Create div with two divs inside that need to stay centered

Tags: html, css

I'm making a web site responsive, and on the home page I should insert two "containers" that should be centered and aligned. (containers in this case are two divs with inside images and text)

I wish they would behave in this way

[image]

and when the page is "restricted", the two divs should position itself in this way

[image]

I tried like this, but it is not exactly what I would get

```
<div style="">
     <div style="width: 300px;float: left;">
        div 1
     </div>

     <div style="width: 300px;float: left;">
        div 2
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no luck with those images..

Comment: Why not use a boilerplate template like Zurb Foundation or Bootstrap? Does all the hard work for you.

Comment: CSS Media queries is the way to go

Comment: I do not want to use the media queries, 
simply because I do not want the contents of the div 2 will resize based on the screen size, I just want the div are positioned one above the other when both can no longer remain within the screen side by side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try to use **display: inline-block** property. In this way you don't have to apply 'overflow' for parent and it's pretty easy to make blocks centered.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box">Div 1</div>
    <div class="box">Div 2</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    text-align: center;

    /* Just decoration */
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 20px;
}
.wrapper .box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;

    /* Just decoration */
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Take a look at the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/caprella/y4BQ3/

Comment: daaaang. Now that's what I call smooth. Almost a hack though since it relies on text-align:center to keep the boxes in the middle

Answer (score 1):

I put something quick together for you. You will have to use media queries to find the size of the page when you want the style to switch. Mess around with my example and you should be able to figure something out to your liking.

```
<div id="box">
     <div class="innerBox">
        div 1
     </div>

     <div class="innerBox">
        div 2
     </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS...

```
#box {
    width:88%;
    background:red;
    padding:20px 6%;
}
.clear{clear:both}
.innerBox {
    width:41%;
    float:left;
    background:blue;
    display:block;
}
.innerBox:first-child {
    margin-right:18%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    #box .innerBox {
        float:none;
        width:100%;
        margin:20px 0 0 0;
    }    
    #box .innerBox:first-child {
        margin-top:0;
    }
}
  }
```

JsFIddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/x3JLX/

Comment: I do not want to use the media queries, 
simply because I do not want the contents of the div 2 will resize based on the screen size, I just want the div are positioned one above the other when both can no longer remain within the screen side by side

Comment: yes, as I responded to the response of dpwivagg, I would like everything to be centered, both at the beginning and after the displacement of the two divs

Comment: Not sure that's possible...without media queries

Answer (score 0):

Check out this Fiddle.  There's only a few simple changes to your existing code, which I included below.
http://jsfiddle.net/ArKKG/

```
<div style="overflow:auto; height: 100% text-align: center;">
    <div style="width: 300px; height: 50px;float: left;">
       div 1
    </div>

    <div style="width: 300px;height: 50px;float: left;">
       div 2
    </div>
</div>
```

And some CSS to make them visible, and keep the borders separated.

```
div{
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 4px;
}
```

Comment: I wish that the two divs would remain at the center